# "The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's domains" when it is

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I'm trying to post to a Facebook wall from a PHP script. I've created a FB app, installed the Graph PHP API, and implemented some test scripts as follows:

**fbinit.php:**

```
<?php

session_start();

require_once('src/Facebook/autoload.php');

$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
'app_id' => 'REDACTED',
'app_secret' => 'REDACTED',
'default_graph_version' => 'v2.9',
]);

?>
```

**fbpost.php:**

```
<?php

include('fbinit.php');

$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();

$permissions = ['manage_pages','publish_pages']; //'publish_actions'
$loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl('https://www.REDACTED.net/fb-callback.php', $permissions);

echo '<a href="' . htmlspecialchars($loginUrl) . '">Log in with Facebook!</a>';

?>
```

**fb-callback.php:**

```
<?php

include('fbinit.php');

$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
$_SESSION['FBRLH_state']=$_GET['state'];

try {

  $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();

} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {

  echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;

} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {

  echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;

}

if (! isset($accessToken)) {
  echo 'No OAuth data could be obtained from the signed request. User has not authorized your app yet.';
  exit;
}

try {

  $response = $fb->get('me/accounts', $accessToken->getValue());
  $response = $response->getDecodedBody();

} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {

  echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;

} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {

  echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;

}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($response);
echo "</pre>";

?>
```

The first time I opened fbpost.php, I was asked to log in to Facebook as expected, and it asked for permission to post on my behalf on the page, which is fine. But then I am redirected to the call back page and presented with the following error:

`Graph returned an error: Can't load URL: The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's domains. To be able to load this URL, add all domains and sub-domains of your app to the App Domains field in your app settings.`

I have added every combination of the app URL's and callback URL's I can think of, but nothing works. See below for screenshots of the app settings. The App ID and secret are definitely correct.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: The value of the `redirect_uri` parameter needs to be the exact same in your login dialog call, and the subsequent API call that tries to exchange the code for a token. When you have generation of the login URL and handling of the response spread over different scripts (i.e., called via different URLs), that can easily lead to problems like this. Try and explicitly specify the callback URL in your `getAccessToken` method call as well.

Comment: Aha, that worked! Specifying the callback URL in getAccessToken() allowed the callback to work and I then got the array representing the pages returned. Thank you! If you post this as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of the `redirect_uri` parameter needs to be the exact same in your login dialog call, and the subsequent API call that tries to exchange the code for a token.

When you have generation of the login URL and handling of the response spread over different scripts (i.e., called via different URLs), that can easily lead to problems like this. The SDK tries to figure out the value based on the current script URL, if left to its own devices.

In such a case, explicitly specify the callback URL in your `getAccessToken` method call as well.

Comment: Specifying the callback URL in getAccessToken() allowed the callback to work and I then got the array representing the pages returned. Thank you!

Comment: Yikes, the one it was generating was the same as the one I supplied but with its own query params added and that was breaking it! Simply passing the same URL without the query params fixed the issue for me, thanks!